# Basic billiards game: Can't detect collision between cuestick and cueball

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics, billiards

I have a basic Unity project on [GitHub](https://github.com/KurtRMueller/BattleBilliards).

Basically, I have a Cuestick that aims and shoots using the mouse. You can rotate around the cueball with your mouse and when you're ready to shoot, you can hold down the right mouse button and move the mouse forward. The game came follows the cuetip.

However, the collision between the cuestick and cueball is wonky. The cuestick protrudes through the ball and only pushes the ball forward only a little bit.

I've created rigid bodies and colliders for both cuestick and cueball. I've set the cuestick's rigid body to kinematic (if it's unchecked, the poolstick will barely dent the ball). I've tried using `OnCollisionEnter` and a `Debug.Log` statement to no avail.

Any help would greatly be appreciated. You can find my scripts in /GameLogic (they're F# sharp scripts whose binaries get compiled and outputted into the /assets folder).

Comment: How are you moving the pool cue? Are you imparting velocities/impulses to it, or manually positioning it via its transform? If it's the latter, then to the physics engine it may appear that it's teleported into the ball, with no particular forward momentum to transfer, so it just resolves the penetration by the smallest displacement/velocity change that it can.

Comment: Additionally if you do use `AddForce()` make sure that you set the *masses* of each object to sensible values.

Answer (score 1):

Why using a complicated collision detection algorithm? Just calculate the distance from the center of the ball to the end of the cuestick. If it's less than or equal to the ball's radius, the cuestick is colliding with the ball.

Comment: I would venture to guess that he wants a decent collision algorithm to model complete rigid body physics. Just detecting a collision like this wouldn't include things like velocity, jerk, spin, acceleration, etc...

Comment: This collision model will easily produce the hit point and normal vectors required to do everything you explained. It is even analytically correct if a cylinder were used instead of a point to represent the stick.